# What other word can I use to say a series of/ collection of (movies, books, plays, etc...)?

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to know the right word to use when I'm talking about a collection (of movies, books, plays, etc...) that has an indefinite amount. I'm looking for a word close to *trilogy*, but I don't exactly want to use that, because it has the prefix "*tri*" meaning "three". I seem to have stumbled upon the word I'm really looking for, but is there really a word somewhat like "*trilogy*" out there? Or was I just imagining things. Any inference would be welcome. Cheers!

Comment: I would stick with *series* since any reader will immediately understand your context.

Comment: What did the thesaurus tell you?

Comment: Series. Plus more letters the meet the minimum count.

Answer (score 2):

The first word I thought of was **anthology**.

> a collection of selected literary pieces or passages or works of art or music

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anthology))

But "series", as suggested by Gary's Student, would probably also work just fine.

Comment: I think of an anthology as being a curated set while a series is specifically written by the author to go together.  It depends on what OP means.

Comment: @Jim Now that you mention it, I agree. I guess it depends upon how exhaustive a "collection" the OP meant.

Comment: +1 I think this is a good answer, especially given the OP's request for a similar word to trilogy. The fact you have included the *ogy* stem is to be applauded I would say.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this word would work for this, but how about *Saga*?

From dictionary.com, [saga](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/saga)

> 1. noun a medieval Icelandic or Norse prose narrative of achievements
>    and events in the history of a personage, family, etc.
> 2. any narrative or legend of heroic exploits. Also called saga novel .
> 3. a form of the novel in which the members or generations of a
>    family or social group are chronicled in a long and leisurely
>    narrative.
> 4. a dramatic history of a group, place, industry, etc.: the
>    saga of the transcontinental railroad.
> 5. any very long story with
>    dramatic events or parts: the sad saga of her life in poverty.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).